# C++; Подключение классов из внешних хедеров

Tags: c++

Имеется такой код:

```
#include "wrad.h"
extern class WRAD;

void Func(WRAD::VisionParams parametrs);
```

Внутри другого хедер файла module.h; Определение Func написано, причем линковщик никаких ошибок не выдает. Но при компиляции вылазит ошибка: C2027 use of undefined type 'WRAD'. В чем кроется загвоздка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибок несколько:

1. Нельзя делать `forward declaration` типа объявленного внутри класса
2. Даже если было можно, то при передаче по значению:
   `void Func(WRAD::VisionParams parametrs);` нужно знать полный тип

Comment: Предлагаешь сделать функцию в классе?